# sqlite3.OperationalError: unrecognized token:

Tags: python, sqlite, bots, sqlite3-ruby

Hello I new in the sqlite world and here is my problem. Trying to fix a twitter bot an error occured. Here is the code to modify and the error. Tell me if you need the entire code or other informations

```
def CreateTables(user):
   connexion = sqlite3.connect('data.db')
   c = connexion.cursor()
   c.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {tab}
   (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE, compte text, date DATE);'''.format(tab=user.screen_name))
   c.close()
   connexion.commit()
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Documents\Terminale\Python\Twitter bot\BotTwitter-master\main.py", line 53, in <module>
    GestionFollow.CreateTables(user)
  File "C:\Users\User\Documents\Terminale\Python\Twitter bot\BotTwitter-master\GestionFollow.py", line 12, in CreateTables
    (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE, compte text, date DATE);'''.format(tab=user.screen_name))
sqlite3.OperationalError: unrecognized token: "361Yra"
```

Comment: unrelated, but do you **really** want to create a table for every user? that's not very scalable.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] which others can run on their computer.

Comment: Could you show the class code for the parameter user?

Comment: This isn't my code I'm just modifying it it already have been coded like this and it seems to work

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to create a table with a name that starts with a digit: `361Yra` and this is not allowed.
What you can do is enclose the name in square brackets: `[361Yra]`
Although I'm not an expert in Python, use something like this:

```
.format(tab="[" + user.screen_name + "]")
```